# How do I create pages within a Wordpress post?

Tags: plugins, functions, pages

I run a music blog and I want to do a countdown of our top 50 tracks of 2011 so far.

There's no way that I want to add 50+ images and Audio Players into just one post, and I don't want to break the post down into separate posts either.

Is there some kind of plugin or function that will allow me to add pages to the post so I could have say 10 tracks per page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress actually comes with pagination built in. I don't believe there's a button on the visual editor by default, but in HTML mode you should be able to insert `<!--nextpage-->` wherever you'd like a page break and it will work. Styling the pagination links would likely be the next step after that: http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links